# Cannot declare a struct in my function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

When I define a `struct` outside my main function there is there is no problem. But when I define it inside the main function it won't compile. Can anyone explain to me why or where is my mistake?

This works:

```
struct student 
{
    char first[100];
    char last[100];
    float grade3[3];
    float ave;
};

void print_out(struct student [] );
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct student dd;
    // ...
    print_out(&dd);
    return 0;
}

void print_out(struct student st[])
{
    // ...
}
```

This does not:

```
void print_out(struct student [] );
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //the only change here by declaring structure inside main function
    struct student 
    {
      char first[100];
      char last[100];
      float grade3[3];
      float ave;
    };
    struct student dd;
    // ...
    print_out(&dd);
    return 0;
}

void print_out(struct student st[])
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @PaulHicks You broke it, now the code uses several  undeclared identifiers , including `n` and `m` and `struct name`. Also the.  I will roll back if not fixed shortly. Check the behaviour with a compiler before posting code.

Comment: Outside definition is a global struct, inside it becomes **auto** storage and cannot be initialized in-line (but can with individual member assignments).  If you want to do this precede it with the **static** storage qualifier.

Comment: @ArifBurhan that is false; struct objects defined at block scope may still be initialized. You may be thinking of variable-length arrays, which may not be initialized. (This is not a VLA because `m` was `#define` as a literal)

Comment: you can try http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about that. All is good now, except the doesn't-work example works! But that's due to not defining `print_out`. I guess I should put that back in for completelness.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is one of scope. In the case that does not work, you're defining your `struct` inside the scope of the `main` function. That `struct` simply does not exist outside of the `main` function.  However you are using it outside the `main` function, in the signature of the `print_out` function.

When you use any custom type, you must declare that type at the same level or a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

`struct student` in second one cannot be seen outside the `main` function as it  is a local variable , can only be used  inside `main`.